# Access embedded json in value

Tags: json, jq, fromjson

Is there any chance to access a embedded json value inside a value?
The assume json example looks like this:

```
{
  "key": "{\"test\":1,\"check\":\"default\"}"
}
```

This is more of a curiosity question.

What I always do today is

```
echo '{"key": "{\"test\":1,\"check\":\"default\"}"}' | jq -r .key | jq .test
```

and I get `1` for this example.

However I am curious if there is any possibility to omit the second jq pipe and to basically dense this down to one jq command.

Comment: `.key | fromjson.test`

Comment: Nice. That worked. Thanks a lot. Don't know how to set a feedback on the comment if you like transport it into an answer and I can vote on it.

Comment: Andre - Appreciate the feedback. You cannot set feedback on comments, except voting it up (left ^). Also if a post is closed as a duplicate, no further answers will be allowed on it. Check StackOverflow Help Center guidelines for [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)